# I'm having a difficult time storing a token in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oop, token

Please help me figure out how to store the token from the script below in a MySQL field. I isolated the problem by doing trial and error tests to find that I was able to store the key, encoded password, but for some reason I'm not able to store the token. What field type should I be using to store it? What length?

```
<?php
require_once('../MySQLi/mysqliConnect.php');

/**
 * Password protection class.
 */
class PasswordCrypt {
    /* Number of rounds to use for PBKDF2 for new setups.
     * May be tweaked up or down because the number of rounds is encoded with the data
     */
    const DEFAULT_PBKDF2_ROUNDS = 10000;

    /* Definition:
     *  Output data = 1 || IV || HMAC_SHA256(K, PROTECT_AES_256_CBC(K, IV, data)) ||  AES_256_CBC(K, IV, data)
     */
    const PROTECT_AES_256_CBC_HMACSHA1 = 1;

    /* Definition:
     *  Uses the PBKDF2 derivation algorithm. The key is encrypted with a protection algorithm..
     *  Output data = 1 || SALT || Rounds (4-byte-integer) || 'Protected' key)
     */
    const TOKEN_PBKDF2_SHA256_AES_256_CBC = 1;

    /* Token which is effectively the key encrypted with the password */
    private $token;

    /* Key used to perform encryption/decryption */
    private $key;

    /* Private constructor that takes the token and key.
     *
     * The token is kept around for storage purposes whereas the key is the main
     * important piece.
     */
    protected function __construct($token, $key) {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance using a given password.
     *
     * @param $password text string from user
     */
    public static function createWithNewPassword($password) {
        /* Generate the new random key to use */
        $key = PasswordCrypt::generateRandomKey();

        /* Generate the token to store */
        $token = PasswordCrypt::encodeProtectedToken($password, $key);

        /* Setup the instance */
        return new PasswordCrypt($token, $key);
    }


    /**
     * Create a new instance given input token and password.
     *
     * @param $password password associated with the given $token
     * @param $token token for the given user
     *
     * @return null if decoding fails, else value instance that can decrypt/encrypt passwords/etc.
     */
    public static function createFromToken($password, $token) {
        $key = PasswordCrypt::decodeProtectedToken($password, $token);
        if (!$key) {
            return null;
        }

        return new PasswordCrypt($token, $key);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance using session data.
     */
    public static function createWithSession() {
        $token = $_SESSION['__pc_token'];
        $sessionKey = $_SESSION['__pc_key'];

        $cookieData = $_COOKIE['__pc_cookie'];
        if (!$token || !$sessionKey || !$cookieData) {
            return null;
        }
        $cookieData = PasswordCrypt::base64url_decode($cookieData);
        $key = PasswordCrypt::decryptData($sessionKey, $cookieData);

        return new PasswordCrypt($token, $key);
    }

    /**
     * Utility function to check if the PHP session state has what is needed for
     * session-based construction.
     */
    public static function hasSessionData() {
        return $_SESSION['__pc_token']
            && $_SESSION['__pc_key']
            && $_COOKIE['__pc_cookie'];
    }

    /**
     * Clear the session state from PHP to prevent re-use (ex: useful for logout)
     */
    public static function clearSessionData() {
        unset($_SESSION['__pc_token']);
        unset($_SESSION['__pc_key']);
        PasswordCrypt::setSessionCookie('__pc_cookie', '');
    }

    /* Utility function to store data in the session and set a cookie to decrypt */
    public function storeSessionKey() {
        $sessionKey = PasswordCrypt::generateRandomKey();
        $cookieData = PasswordCrypt::encryptData($sessionKey, $this->key);

        $_SESSION['__pc_token'] = $this->token;
        $_SESSION['__pc_key'] = $sessionKey;
        PasswordCrypt::setSessionCookie('__pc_cookie', PasswordCrypt::base64url_encode($cookieData));
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to set a session cookie - tweak as appropriate for proper cookie settings for the site.
     */
    private static function setSessionCookie($name, $value) {
        /* Store for session only and assume total path... */
        $secure = false;
        if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) {
            $secure = TRUE;
        }
        setcookie($name, $value, 0, "", "", $secure, TRUE);
    }

    /**
     * Method to decode passwords previously encoded.
     *
     * @param $ciphertext raw binary string representing the encrypted password.
     *
     * @return decoded password string as passed in to encodePassword.
     * null may be returned if the data is corrupt, uses a format not supported by
     * this version, or does not match the key.
     */
    /**
    * Method to use MySQL functions
    * Beginning of added code
    */
    public function MySQL()
    {
        $query = "SELECT password_key FROM pwmkey";
        $connection = $check_connection->db_connect();
        $result = mysqli_query($check_connection,$query);
        $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }       


    /**
    *End of added code
    */
    public function decodePassword($ciphertext) {
    /* Changed first parameter in decryptData from $this->key to $InsideOutsideKey */
        return PasswordCrypt::decryptData($this->key,$ciphertext);
    }

    /**
     * Method to encode passwords to later be decoded using decodePassword.
     *
     * @param $password text representing the data to protect - may be raw binary.
     *
     * @return encrypted password data in raw binary form. null will be returned if
     * something is critically wrong with the setup - not likely.
     */
    public function encodePassword($password) {
        return PasswordCrypt::encryptData($this->key, $password);
    }

    /**
     * Method to create a new token protected with a new password.
     * Useful for when the user wants to change their password.
     *
     * @param $password new password to encode against.
     *
     * @return token to later be decoded using the provided password.
     */
    public function encodeToken($password) {
        return PasswordCrypt::encodeProtectedToken($password, $this->key);
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the current token as protected by the initial password input.
     *
     * @return token to later be decoded using the initial password at creation.
     */
    public function getToken() {
        return $this->token;
    }
    /**
    *Method to get a random key used by AES-256
    */
    public function getKey() {
        return $this->key;
    }
    /**
     * Utility method to generate a random key as required by AES-256
     */
    private static function generateRandomKey() {
        /* Since using AES 256 CBC - we need 256 bits */
        return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(256 / 8);
    }

    /* Generate the protected token data */
    private static function encodeProtectedToken($password, $key) {
        $implementation = PasswordCrypt::TOKEN_PBKDF2_SHA256_AES_256_CBC;
        switch ($implementation) {
        case PasswordCrypt::TOKEN_PBKDF2_SHA256_AES_256_CBC:
            /* Generate fresh salt to prevent rainbow table attacks */
            $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
            /* Use the defaults configured */
            $iterations = PasswordCrypt::DEFAULT_PBKDF2_ROUNDS;
            /* Derive the key using PBKDF2 with SHA256 per the token key generation scheme */
            $passwordDerivedKey = PasswordCrypt::pbkdf2("SHA256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 256 / 8, true);
            /* Encrypt the 'real' key data using the password-based key */
            $data = PasswordCrypt::encryptData($passwordDerivedKey, $key);
            return pack("Ca16La*", $implementation, $salt, $iterations, $data);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* Decode the protected token data */
    private static function decodeProtectedToken($password, $tokenData) {
        list(,$implementation) = unpack("C", $tokenData);
        switch ($implementation) {
        case PasswordCrypt::TOKEN_PBKDF2_SHA256_AES_256_CBC:
            /* Extract the salt encoded in the protection data */
            $salt = substr($tokenData, 1, 16);
            /* Extract the number of iterations used for this data */
            list(,$iterations) = unpack("L", substr($tokenData, 1 + 16, 4));
            /* Extract the encrypted key data */
            $encrypted = substr($tokenData, 1 + 16 + 4);
            /* Derive the key using PBKDF2 with SHA256 per the token key generation scheme */
            $passwordDerivedKey = PasswordCrypt::pbkdf2("SHA256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 256 / 8, true);
            /* Decrypt the key data using the derived key */
            return PasswordCrypt::decryptData($passwordDerivedKey, $encrypted);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* Protect data using a given input key */
    private static function encryptData($key, $plaintext) {
        $implementation = PasswordCrypt::PROTECT_AES_256_CBC_HMACSHA1;
        switch ($implementation) {
        case PasswordCrypt::PROTECT_AES_256_CBC_HMACSHA1:
            /* Some PHP versions to not have OPENSSL_RAW_DATA option and instead use a boolean for raw, so handle it */
            $options = defined("OPENSSL_RAW_DATA") ? OPENSSL_RAW_DATA : true;
            /* 16-byte IV */
            $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

            /* Encrypt the data first */
            $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, "aes-256-cbc", bin2hex($key), $options, $iv);
            /* Generate an HMAC over the data to make sure final output matches */
            $hmac = hash_hmac("sha1", $encrypted, $key, TRUE);
            /* HMAC should be 160 bits long - 20 bytes */
            return pack("Ca16a20A*", $implementation, $iv, $hmac, $encrypted);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /* Decoded protected data with a given key */
    private static function decryptData($key, $ciphertext) {
        list(,$implementation) = unpack("C", $ciphertext);
        switch ($implementation) {
        case PasswordCrypt::PROTECT_AES_256_CBC_HMACSHA1:
            $iv = substr($ciphertext, 1, 16);
            $included_hmac = substr($ciphertext, 1 + 16, 20);
            $encrypted = substr($ciphertext, 1 + 16 + 20);
            /* Verify the HMAC */
            $hmac = hash_hmac("sha1", $encrypted, $key, TRUE);
            if ($hmac != $included_hmac) {
                /* HMAC did not match, bad key or corrupt data */
                return null;
            }
            /* Some PHP versions to not have OPENSSL_RAW_DATA option and instead use a boolean for raw, so handle it */
            $options = defined("OPENSSL_RAW_DATA") ? OPENSSL_RAW_DATA : true;
            $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, "aes-256-cbc", bin2hex($key), $options, $iv);
            return $decrypted;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*
     * PBKDF2 key derivation function as defined by RSA's PKCS #5: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt
     * $algorithm - The hash algorithm to use. Recommended: SHA256
     * $password - The password.
     * $salt - A salt that is unique to the password.
     * $count - Iteration count. Higher is better, but slower. Recommended: At least 1000.
     * $key_length - The length of the derived key in bytes.
     * $raw_output - If true, the key is returned in raw binary format. Hex encoded otherwise.
     * Returns: A $key_length-byte key derived from the password and salt.
     *
     * Test vectors can be found here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt
     *
     * This implementation of PBKDF2 was originally created by https://defuse.ca
     * With improvements by http://www.variations-of-shadow.com
     */
    private static function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false) {
        $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
        if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true)) {
            trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0) {
            trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        /* If we have a version of PHP with the native hash_pbkdf2 - use that! */
        if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
            // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
            if (!$raw_output) {
                $key_length = $key_length * 2;
            }
            return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
        }
        $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
        $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);
        $output = "";
        for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
            // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
            $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
            // first iteration
            $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
            // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
            for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
                $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
            }
            $output .= $xorsum;
        }
        if($raw_output) {
            return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
        } else {
            return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
        }
    }
    private static function base64url_encode($data) {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    }

    private static function base64url_decode($data) {
        return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You mean the return value of `encodeProtectedToken`? That depends on the password. I'd say (without testing) the "header" is 58 bytes long and then there's an increment of 16 bytes per block; len(password) between 0-15->74 bytes result, 16-31->90 bytes result and so on.

Comment: I am referring to the encodeProtectedToken return value. What kind of field should I store it in and does the character type of the field matter. I have it set to a very long length long enough to fit the Token in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a binary field in the table, e.g. a [varbinary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html), you can use a [prepared statement](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and bind the token parameter as a blob and then send the actual data via [mysqli_stmt::send_long_data](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    trigger_error( sprintf('mysqli connect error (%d) %s', $mysqli->connect_errno, $mysqli->connect_error), E_USER_ERROR);
    die;
}
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT|MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
$mysqli->query('
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
        id int auto_increment,
        x varbinary(128),
        primary key(id)
    )
');

$token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(96); // just some binary data

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (x) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('b', $foo);
$stmt->send_long_data(0, $token);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = null;

foreach( $mysqli->query('SELECT x FROM soFoo WHERE id=1') as $row ) {
    var_export($token===$row['x']);
}
```

This will *probably* also work with just binding a string parameter.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (x) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $token);
$stmt->execute();
```

edit: Using a prepared statement having multiple blob parameters:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (x, y, anInteger, largeblob) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('bbib', $foo, $foo, $n, $foo);

// the first parameter of send_long_data specificies the positional parameter of the prep.statement, starting with 0
$stmt->send_long_data(0, $token); // the data "for" x
$stmt->send_long_data(1, $token); // the data "for" y

// assume a case where the data for largeblob might potentially be larger than max_client_packet
// there's an integer parameter that already "has its data" between the last blob and this one, so this is parameter #3
while( !feof($fp) ) { // the loop is a bit oversimplified; you would probably have a more error handling in production code....
    $stmt->send_long_data(3, fread($fp, 4096)); // the next data chunk "for" largeblob
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt = null;
```

As mentioned in my last comment, using send_long_data() is in no way, shape or form *a must*. If you want to, I suggest you start at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html
and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html

as grounds to make the decision whether this is for you or not ;-)

Comment: How would I go about doing this with multiple fields and values. I'm not used to using mysqli prepared statements. Also, could you explain to me why the prepared statement is necessary in this instance?

Comment: Hehe, I just had a discussion the other day with a collegue about why I'm so fixated on prepared statements and named parameters (caused by another comment I left here on SO). a) I'm not ;-) b) There _are_ other ways. It's just about what I endorse by default in a "forum" like this. I don't know anything about your skill set, the environment in which this code snippet will be used and how much time and effort you will put into the topic. Same for anybody else who will find this answer e.g. via google. So, I could write books ...or choose one solution I'm comfortable with (to err on).

Comment: I just wanted to tell you that thanks to your help I have been able to successfully store the token, which has been a hitch in my get a long for a while preventing me from making my website. Anyway, on to bigger and better things I suppose. Thanks VolkerK, you're the best.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I asked about why prepared statements were necessary, what I really wanted to ask is why is bind_param() necessary to store the token? In other words, why can't I just store it by inserting it into MySQL with the regular INSERT?

Comment: You can do that. There's a description in the string-literals page I've linked to, beginning with "If you want to insert binary data". And even in that section binding parameters is mentioned ;-)

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$MySQLi_String);
 $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE customers SET token=? WHERE customer_id=?');
 $stmt->bind_param('si',$token,$lastid);
 $tf = $stmt->execute();
 echo '<br>' . $tf . '<br>' . $token . '<br>' . $lastid;

Comment: Oh, doh, addslashes() was all I needed to use the INSERT. I guess you have to be careful about long strings having special characters and make sure you escape them. I'll definitely read those links you posted. Strings are tricky things indeed.

Comment: see http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string (2006)